# Processing influx db output of 'influxdb.resultset.ResultSet'

Tags: python-2.7, influxdb

I am trying to integrate influxdb with my application and process the output. I am importing InfluxDBClient package to connect to influx instance running on my local machine. Using query() that returns data in  'influxdb.resultset.ResultSet' format.

However, I want to be able to pick each element specifically from the Resultset for my computations. I was using different functions like keys(), items() and values() from the influxdb-python manual here but of no use: 
http://influxdb-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api-documentation.html

This is the sample output of the query():

> Result: ResultSet({'(u'cpu', None)': [{u'usage_guest_nice': 0, u'usage_user': 0.90783871790308868, u'usage_nice': 0, u'usage_steal': 0, u'usage_iowait': 0.056348610076366427, u'host': u'xxx.xxx.hostname.com', u'usage_guest': 0, u'usage_idle': 98.184322579062794, u'usage_softirq': 0.0062609566755314457, u'time': u'2016-06-26T16:25:00Z', u'usage_irq': 0, u'cpu': u'cpu-total', u'usage_system': 0.84522915123660536}]})

I am also finding it hard to get the data in JSON format using Raw mentioned in the above link. Would be great to have any pointers to process the above output.

Comment: You write that *"I was using different functions (...) but of no use:"* and that *"I am also finding it hard to get the data in JSON format (...)"*. What was the output of these attempts? Could you post the code that doesn't work as expected?

Comment: Realized that I can get the data throught items(). It returns the measurement as key and data in generator format which I could loop into and get the data in Key-value(Dictionary) format. This helped me fix the problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

items() returns a tuple in below format, ((u'cpu', None), ), where the generator can be used to loop and get the actual data in Dictionary format. Took some time for me to figure out but it was fun!!

Comment: Can you put up an example?

Answer (score 2):

According to [the docs](http://influxdb-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/resultset.html) you could use the `get_points()` function to retrieve results from an InfluxDB resultset. The function allows you to filter by either *measurement*, *tag*, both *measurement* AND *tag*, or simply get all the results without any filtering.

**Getting all points**

Using `rs.get_points()` will return a generator for all the points in the ResultSet.

**Filtering by measurement**

Using `rs.get_points('cpu')` will return a generator for all the points that are in a serie with measurement name cpu, no matter the tags.

```
rs = cli.query("SELECT * from cpu") 
cpu_points = list(rs.get_points(measurement='cpu'))
```

**Filtering by tags**
Using `rs.get_points(tags={'host_name': 'influxdb.com'})` will return a generator for all the points that are tagged with the specified tags, no matter the measurement name.

```
rs = cli.query("SELECT * from cpu")
cpu_influxdb_com_points = list(rs.get_points(tags={"host_name": "influxdb.com"}))
```

**Filtering by measurement and tags**
Using measurement name and tags will return a generator for all the points that are in a serie with the specified measurement name AND whose tags match the given tags.

```
rs = cli.query("SELECT * from cpu")
points = list(rs.get_points(measurement='cpu', tags={'host_name': 'influxdb.com'}))
```