# Getting value from InfluxDB into a usable number

Tags: python, influxdb

I am trying to read the last value from a temperature log, and then pass that to a function to determine next steps.

I can get the dataframe by querying the database;

```
result=influxdb_client.query('select last(value) from temperature')
```

This returns;

```
ResultSet({'('temperature', None)': [{'time': '2020-12-11T08:03:34.267109Z', 'last': 19.4}]})
```

But I cannot for the life of me extract the value `19.4` from this.

I've tried the suggestion from the [documentation](https://influxdb-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/resultset.html#getting-all-points);

```
points=result.get_points(measurement='temperature')
```

However this just gives me;

```
<generator object ResultSet.get_points at 0x10aa3d780>
```

Would someone please help this poor lost soul...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/50158162/12451425) helps you.
Cast the result to list and then you reach the values as a normal list.

**EDIT**

After casting it to list convert to dictionary:

```
points_dict = eval(points[0])
```

You can use `ast.literal_eval` instead of eval for additional security if the source is untrusted.

```
from ast import literal_eval
points_dict = dict(literal_eval(points[0]))
```

Comment: Using the example I can get to a python list where the output is;

{'time': '2020-12-13T07:15:05.270373Z', 'last': 13.4}

However this whole segment is just one item in the list (list[0] = the above)

How can I extract that 13.4 number?

Comment: OK I managed to get the number by this horrible method;

'points=list(result.get_points(measurement='temperature'))
st=str(points)
short_st=st[-7:-2]
num_st=float(st1)
print(num_st)'


It's a terrible way of getting there though

Answer (score 0):

OK I managed to get the number by this horrible method;

```
points=list(result.get_points(measurement='temperature'))
```

This returns;

```
[{'time': '2020-12-11T09:28:31.868325Z', 'last': 17.5}]
```

If I then do the following I get the result I'm after

```
st=str(points)
short_st=st[-7:-2]
num_st=float(st1)
print(num_st)
```

It's a terrible way of getting there though